# Execute script before Ubuntu system get shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I want to run my script before the ***ubuntu*** system get shutdown . So for that I have created my script inside `/etc/init.d` directory and make it executable i.e. `chmod +x K99pr.sh`.

Also created another script inside the `/etc/rc0.d` and make it executable like above.
And write my logic in that script.

Now I want to symbolic link to the `/etc/rc0.d/K99prak.sh` from `init.d/K99pr.sh`

Please advice me how to write the symbolic link for above script. I am new for the scripting.

This is my script files

```
 /etc/init.d/K99pr.sh

  #!/bin/bash
  I want add here the symbolic link
```

This is another script:

```
/etc/rc0.d/K99pra.sh

  #!/bin/bash
  my logic
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this best is to have your script "myscript.sh" in the `/etc/init.d/` folder.

Then, make a symbolic link in `/etc/rc0.d/` pointing to `/etc/init.d/myscript.sh`.  You use the `ln` command to make the link.  The command format for the symbolic link you want is:

```
ln -s < target> < link name>
```

or

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/myscript.sh /etc/rc0.d/S05pra.sh
```

Then when shutdown starts, the contents of "myscript.sh" will be run.

The scripts are run in numeric order so 05 would run before 99.  Also, I would recommend calling it S##myscript.sh since you are not killing the myscript.sh service, but instead doing something new at shutdown.

Comment: but in which file I have to add the symbolic link. Is it in myscript.sh or S05ora.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should add in **K99pr.sh** script:

```
Start scripts S##<base script name>
```

The ## represent the order this script should be executed in its runlevel .

You can view its order by :

```
`ls /etc/rc#.d/K*` change # to the number of the runlevel .
```

Comment: base name means without .sh